# org.jetbrains.skiko.LibraryLoadException: Cannot find libskiko-macos-arm64.dylib.sha256, proper native dependency missing

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, apple-m1, skia

I try to compile https://github.com/CuriousNikhil/k5-compose in IntelliJ (Apple-Silicon) on an M1 MacbookPro, I got the below error

```
Caused by: org.jetbrains.skiko.LibraryLoadException: Cannot find libskiko-macos-arm64.dylib.sha256, proper native dependency missing.
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.Library.load(Library.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.HardwareLayer.<clinit>(HardwareLayer.kt:10)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the build.gradle.kts of the project, change     `implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)` to `implementation(compose.desktop.macos_arm64)`

Comment: Thanks - I was building a jar on arch linux and deploying to a raspberry pi and this was my problem. Compose on a pi ftw.

Answer (score 5):

While I found the accepted answer to work:

> Changing
>
> `implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)`
>
> to
>
> `implementation(compose.desktop.macos_arm64)`

The [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Getting_Started#ide-plugin) seems to indicate that you should just update the version of the wizard:

> The Compose plugin version used in the wizard above might not be the latest. Update to the latest plugin version by editing the `build.gradle.kts` file and updating the version information as shown below. For the [latest versions](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/releases), see the latest versions site and the [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) site.

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.2.2"
}
```

Which also works, and I think should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error, but for Linux.

```
Cannot find libskiko-linux-x64.so.sha256, proper native dependency missing.
```

Updating everything to the latest version and replacing `currentOs` with `linux_x64` made no difference, still the same error.

After explicitly adding a dependency on skiko in `build.gradle.kts`, it worked fine.

```kotlin
implementation("org.jetbrains.skiko:skiko-awt-runtime-linux-x64:0.7.69")
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the documentation of Skiko itself and found out that they suggest manually importing it the following way (the `version` may differ):

```
val osName = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val targetOs = when {
        osName == "Mac OS X" -> "macos"
        osName.startsWith("Win") -> "windows"
        osName.startsWith("Linux") -> "linux"
        else -> error("Unsupported OS: $osName")
    }

    val targetArch = when (val osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch")) {
        "x86_64", "amd64" -> "x64"
        "aarch64" -> "arm64"
        else -> error("Unsupported arch: $osArch")
    }

    val version = "0.7.70" // or any more recent version
    val target = "${targetOs}-${targetArch}"

    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.skiko:skiko-awt-runtime-$target:$version")
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
           }
      }
}
```

I simply put this into the following (in the `build.gradle.kts`):

`kotlin {}`

but I think this also works when you just put it outside of it. But the implementation has to be in the `dependencies {}` of course . This solution solved the problem perfectly for me. I also tried to change `implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)` to `implementation(compose.desktop.macos_arm64)` but it didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error today on Intel x64 iMac, and solved by upgrading plugins version.
**kotlin("jvm")** from 1.5.31 to 1.6.10 and **id("org.jetbrains.compose")** from 1.0.0 to 1.1.1
FYI, it worked fine a month ago.